# How to remove log 4j default info of timestamp and log level from the created file in android?

Tags: android, log4j

I have created a log 4 j file in sdcard by the available source in GitHub. Here is output

```
2013-03-04 06:21:14,097 - [DEBUG::abc::com.newvisioninteractive.androidlog4jprototype.SampleClass] - test test!
2013-03-04 06:21:14,101 - [INFO::abc::com.newvisioninteractive.androidlog4jprototype.SampleClass] - abc
```

My question is to remove all the default info of file like, time stamp of filecreation & "DEBUG" or "INFO" package info.In short I want only String "test test!" in first line and "abc" in second line of file.

Please suggest me the possible solution.

Comment: What's your log4j configuration?

Comment: public static void configure() {
  final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();

  logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + File.separator + "myapp.log");
  logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
  // Set log level of a specific logger
  logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
  logConfigurator.configure();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the method *configure()*:

```
     logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%m%n");
```